# Huge space between list view and other widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a container contains a column of containers and listviews .. in this way: 1. container 2. listview 3. container 4. listview ... I did it this way:

```
Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 20.0, left: 20.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      "header1",
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: titles.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0),
                        child: .......
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 20.0, left: 20.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: new Text(
                      "header2",
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: titles.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return new Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 0.0),
                        child: .....
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

i can't remove Expanded from the listview .. if i did the list view will not appear inside the column ..

Also, I tried to use Flexible but the same problem is there ..

this does what i need .. but there's a huge space between the first listview and the second container .. how to remove this empty space and make the listview height wrap depending on the height of the content?

Comment: Have you try to set padding of the ListView to EdgeInsets.zero ?

Comment: @GoonNguyen yes .. and still the same .. there's a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 20.0, left: 20.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
          child: new Text(
            "header1",
          ),
        ),
        color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: titles.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 15.0),
              child: ListTile(title: Text(titles[index]),)
          );
        },
      ),
      Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 20.0, left: 20.0, top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
          child: new Text(
            "header2",
          ),
        ),
        color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: titles.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 0.0),
              child: ListTile(title: Text(titles[index]),)
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: still there's the space i want to remove :(